# The File is not playing After Saving it as Audio file

Tags: java, android

I am generating a tone in android which is being played using audiotrack (object of AudiTrack) , but I want to save this tone as an audio file in Phone or sd card.  The code is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     // int j=2;
     private final int duration = 3; // seconds
     private final int sampleRate = 8000;
     private final int numSamples = duration * sampleRate;
     private final double sample[] = new double[numSamples];
     private final double freqOfTone = 500; // hz

     private final byte generatedSnd[] = new byte[2 * numSamples];

     Handler handler = new Handler();

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     }

     @Override
     protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();

      // Use a new tread as this can take a while
      Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            genTone();
            handler.post(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
         playSound();
        }
       });
          }   
        });
        thread.start();
     }

     void genTone(){
      // fill out the array
      for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; ++i) {
       sample[i] = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / (sampleRate/freqOfTone));
       //System.out.println("the value is ::"+sample[i]);

      }

      // convert to 16 bit pcm sound array
      // assumes the sample buffer is normalised.
      int idx = 0;
      int loop = 0;
      boolean flip =false;
      for (double dVal : sample) {
       short val = (short) (dVal * 32767);
       generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);

        //System.out.println("the value at address"+generatedSnd[idx-1]);
       generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);
       if(flip)
       {
           generatedSnd[idx-1]=(byte)(generatedSnd[idx-1]*2);
           generatedSnd[idx-2]=(byte)(generatedSnd[idx-2]*2);
       }


       System.out.println("the value is:"+generatedSnd[idx-1]);
       System.out.println("the value is::"+generatedSnd[idx-2]);

       loop++;
       if(loop==16){
              loop=0;
              flip=!flip;
          }

      }
     }


     void playSound(){
      AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
        8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, numSamples,
        AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
     // audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, generatedSnd.length);
     audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, numSamples);
     audioTrack.play();
     String sFileName="tonegenerator.mp3"; //String sBody =generatedSnd.toString();
     try
        {
            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Notes");
            if (!root.exists()) {
                root.mkdirs();
            }
            File gpxfile = new File(root, sFileName);
          //  FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
            FileOutputStream writer=new FileOutputStream(gpxfile);
            writer.write(generatedSnd, 0, numSamples);


            //writer.write(generatedSnd, 0, numSamples);
          //  writer.write(generatedSnd);
           // writer.append(sBody);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
             e.printStackTrace();
            // importError = e.getMessage();
            // iError();
        }

     }


    }
```

Now The file is also being saved into the folder called "Notes" . the file tonegenerator.mp3 does not play in the phone and System also.If my code is not correct for storing it. then how should we store it.

Comment: A file doesn't become a valid mp3 file just because you give it the file ending ".mp3". What you're writing to the file looks like header-less uncompressed PCM.

Answer (score 1):

```
AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
    8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, numSamples,
    AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
```

Try changing that size argument from numSamples to the length of generatedSnd array.
And similarly,

```
audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, numSamples);
```

.. set the 3rd argument to the length of that array.

Also, you are not generating an mp3, but a wav file.

Update: based on the fact that you aren't being able to play that file from the disk version:

For a wav file, you need to write the WAV header also. It is described [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/). Example code for reading and writing such files can be seen [here](http://thiscouldbebetter.wordpress.com/2011/08/14/reading-and-writing-a-wav-file-in-java/), esp see writeToFilePath_WriteChunks and the related methods.

If you want the output in some other format, then you will have to use the corresponding file format.

Comment: thanks ankit.. but my concern is to write the generated tone into phone or sd card as an audio file.

Comment: Writing to phone/sdcard won't be any different for this kind of file. You mentioned that it doesn't play on 'system' (computer i guess) either. Did that get fixed with the suggested change?

Comment: yes exactly, phone/sdcard won't be any different for this kind of file. Here :                                  audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, numSamples); write this into audiotrack which plays well when i use             audioTrack.play(); but when i am writing it as a file (suppose creating a file tonegenerator.wav or .mp3,etc. any kind of audio file) using these bytes(same as we write on audioTrack). So the file is being saved which looks like an audio file but on playing it does not play.because somewhere there is error in creating the audio file using bytes.